# An AVL tree is a BST, but AVL tree can be not complete, then why do we define AVL tree a BST?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-trees

An AVL tree is a BST, and a BST is a complete tree, but AVL tree doesn't necessarily have to be complete. Thus, why do we define AVL tree a BST?

Comment: BSTs are usually not assumed to be complete.

Comment: If your resource uses incompatible definitions, get a better one.

Comment: Perhaps you confused BSTs with binary heaps?

Comment: Yes! Thanks guys! Especially@harold you enlighted me. I learned BST first and then heap, and when I looked back to AVLTree I confused mixed BST with heap property I guess. I will now either downvote this question or delete it. Thanks